# How to set cursor at desired position in a row/col of the tableLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, set, position

I am working in Android 1.6 , Java 1.5

We are developing a crossword application in that we have developed the UI screen by using table layout, I have made rows and col cells in the one activity and across clue and down clue in a separate activity. When the user clicks on the across / down clue question the user should automatically navigate to the game activity and it should point out the cell values that belongs to the clues. All the cells that belong to the clue should be shaded in grey color. I am having the cell position but how can I set the colors in that particular rows/cols.

Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getChildAt(int index)` method, it is inherited from `LinearLayout`, and then you can do what you want to a particular cell.